# How can I fix the error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch" when trying to install PyTorch using pip?

Tags: tensorflow, import, pip, pytorch

I tried importing 'PyTorch' as 'torch' as most recent, but visual studios/cmd cannot locate nor download the package.

`# Import the required modules import torch import torch.nn as nn import torch.nn.functional as F`

same goes with

`import tensorflow as tk`

I wasn't able to download the package:
not able to find the file.

I tried both:
`pip install --upgrade pip`

and:
`pip install torch==1.0.2`

I tried all types such the basic pip install [package] to connecting the wsl.file through path

Answer (score 0):

Installing older torch needs --find-index flag to pip, like torch 1.5 with cuda 10.1:

`pip install torch==1.5.0+cu101 torchvision==0.6.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Reference:

https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/